# Typeahead get remote data issue

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, typeahead.js

I have some products in my database and I have used an input field for searching products.
I am using [Typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) for search products with remote data. My database for products is like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `desc` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

INSERT INTO `products` (`id_product`, `name`, `desc`) VALUES
(1,  'Apple', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry'),
(2,  'Box ', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry'),
(2,  'Bat ', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry'),
(2,  'Cat ', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry'),
(2,  'Ant ', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry');
```

And the html with js is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.typeahead.css">
<style>
.tt-query,
.tt-hint {
    width: 396px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    outline: none;
}

.tt-query {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.tt-hint {
    color: #999
}

.tt-dropdown-menu {
    width: 422px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.tt-suggestion {
    padding: 3px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0097cf;

}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
        //<![CDATA[ 
        $(window).load(function () {
            // instantiate the bloodhound suggestion engine
            var products = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: function (d) {
                    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
                },
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                remote: {
                    url: 'ajax.php?search_term=%QUERY',
                    filter: function (products) {
                        return $.map(products.results, function (product) {
                            return {
                                value: product.name
                            };
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            // initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
            products.initialize();
            // instantiate the typeahead UI
            $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
                displayKey: 'value',
                source: products.ttAdapter()
            });
        }); //]]>
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <input class='typeahead' placeholder='Find products...' type='text' />
</body>
</html>
```

In ajax.php I have used my custom query like this

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=products';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$query = $_REQUEST['search_term'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name from `products` WHERE `name`  LIKE '%".$query."%' ");
$stmt->bindParam(':query', $query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

// populate results
$results = array();
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) as $row) {
    $results[] = $row;
}
print_r($results);

// and return to typeahead
echo json_encode($results);
```

here its in array I am getting the products name like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bat
    [1] => Box
)
```

with json I am also getting the data like this

```
["Bat","Box"]
```

But I don't know why the values are not coming in the search dropdown box? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

**Note**
In console I am getting error like

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: What errors you get in console?

Comment: You have `return {value: product.name};` but your json does not have `name` keys. Maybe try `$results[] = array('name'=>$row);` in your `ajax.php`

Comment: @Sean still I am nt getting the results. In console I am getting error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Your json is `products` -> `function (products)`, so why are you doing `products.results` -> `return $.map(products.results, function(product)`? You don't have a `results` property in `products`.

Comment: @Sean I had taken the code from this link http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/UkB7u/

Comment: @NewUser can you also post the complete JSON response that you are getting?

Comment: If you look at your examples returned data the json looks like `{results: { original_title:...},{ original_title:...},...}`.

Comment: So try changing your `ajax.php` code to `$results['results'][] = array('name'=>$row);` if you don't want to change your js code.

Comment: @Sean thanks that worked. Just post this in answer with description as still I am confused how it worked. So that I can accept the answer and the users with the same issue can get help from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your typehead js code is

```
                filter: function (products) {
                    return $.map(products.results, function (product) {
                        return {
                            value: product.name
                        };
                    });
                }
```

namely `products.results.name` you need to format your php array so that it returns the json object properly

```
// populate results
$results = array();
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) as $row) {

    //add to 'results' with array with key 'name'
    $results['results'][] = array('name'=>$row);

}

// and return to typeahead
echo json_encode($results);
```